# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate timeout install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I get the following error:

> This operation returned because the timeout period expired.

Any solutions?
 I've tried searching, but nothing useful.

Thanks in advance.

I'm running Windows 8.1.

Comment: Even when I try installing Microsoft C++ Redistributable Package 2013, I get the same error.

Comment: could you give us some more info on the error? the logs in your %temp% folder, a screenshot of the error. when exactly does it occur?

Answer (score 1):

Try: Cancel Hyper-V instances of the Emulator (Virtual Machines) already running and possibly in a corrupt state.

Close Visual Studio.
Open up Hyper-V Manager; stop and remove any instances of VMs that are present.
Try: Remove/Disable third party drivers or software that may be interfering with virtual networking

For Details check the link 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/b06cc9f2-aa5e-4cb3-9df1-0c273e1dfd68/wp8-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading `vs_ultimate_download.exe` from [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs).  Run it and it'll download all the files (this can take a while).

Then run `vs_ultimate.exe`.